# Bugify on Openshift

Tags: php, git, openshift

Is anyone able to help me setup Bugify on Openshift.
If you managed to get Bugify working on Openshift please let me know as this is a problem which is taking me ages to solve.

After you've resolved these issues, we'll carry on with the installation. Refresh the page after you've fixed an issue.

1. Bugify needs write access to all its files. Please run:
   chown -R *openshift account number* /var/lib/openshift/*openshift account number*/app-root/runtime/repo/php/bugify and then
   chmod -R 744 /var/lib/openshift/*openshift account number*/app-root/runtime/repo/php/bugify

I ran both these commands through the rhc ssh *openshift account number*, but then it did nothing and a refresh of the page and a restart of the application also did not make the error message go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you following a set of instructions or are you trying to get this working on your own?

By default your `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` (~/app-root/runtime/repo) is owned by you:

> > pwd
>   /var/lib/openshift/544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd/app-root/runtime/repo
>
> > ls -la total 64 drwxr-x---. 4 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd
>   544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd  4096 Oct 23 14:32 . drwxr-x---. 5
>   544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd    85 Nov 11 07:26
>   ..
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd   444 Oct 23 14:32 deplist.txt
>   -rwxrwxr--. 1 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 39585 Oct 23 14:32 index.html drwxr-xr-x. 2 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd
>   544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd    21 Oct 23 14:32 node_modules drwxr-xr-x. 5
>   544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd    66 Oct 23 14:32
>   .openshift
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd   666 Oct 23 14:32 package.json
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd   137 Oct 23 14:32 README.md
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd 544949a4e0b8cd16540000bd  4631 Oct 23 14:32 server.js [node-niharvey.rhcloud.com repo]>

I changed the permissions of my index.html to 744 like you mentioned so you should have no trouble changing your bugify folder.

Here's what you should do:

1. rhc ssh
2. cd into `~/app-root/runtime/repo`
3. Run your chmod commands

Fair warning that this isn't permanent. Everytime you do a git push from your local machine it will reset these permissions (see OpenShift App Deployments). In order to make this permanent you'll need to create an action hook changing the permissions https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-modifying-applications.html.